# How to insert an item at the beginning of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I know how to insert it to the end by:

```
$arr[] = $item;
```

But how to insert it to the beginning?

Comment: `$arr[-1] = $item;`
Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252657/669677

Comment: @2astalavista, that doesn't work: `print_r($arr)` => `Array ( [0] => a, [1] => b, [-1] => c )`

Comment: @returnthis.lau_ this case you should use for loop - starting from -1 - to make it work: `for ($i = -1; $i < count($a)-1; $i++)` as the referenced link showed, but it is easy to forget, so I don't prefer that solution any more.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Use [array_unshift($array, $item);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

```
$arr = array('item2', 'item3', 'item4');
array_unshift($arr , 'item1');
print_r($arr);
```

will give you

```
Array
(
 [0] => item1
 [1] => item2
 [2] => item3
 [3] => item4
)
```

Comment: What about if you need literal, rather than numeric, keys?

Comment: @Evan, the documentation for `array_unshift` says the following `All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.`

Comment: There are two problem: 1)reindexing the array 2)can not add item with an index.

Comment: If you have an associative array or need to preserve keys then see the user examples here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php there are a couple good examples of how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 154):

In case of an associative array or numbered array where you do not want to change the array keys:

```
$firstItem = array('foo' => 'bar');

$arr = $firstItem + $arr;
```

`array_merge` does not work as it always reindexes the array.

Comment: Attention! "The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored." -- See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140094/3411766

Comment: The solution it's good because can add item with an index, and didn't reindexing the array; But have just a note about remove item in the right hand array, if there are same index in the left hand array.

Answer (score 23):

Since **PHP7.4** you can use the spread opperator, very similar to JavaScript

```php
$arr = [$item, ...$arr];
```

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

A few more examples:

```php
// Add an item before
$arr = [$item, ...$arr];

// Add an item after
$arr = [...$arr, $item];

// Add a few more
$arr = [$item1, $item2, ...$arr, $item3];

// Multiple arrays and and items
$arr = [$item1, ...$arr1, $item2, ...$arr2, $item3];
```

- Note: this is only possible with int keys, not for associative arrays.
- Note2: The keys are not kept.

**BREAKING Example:**

```php
$car = ['brand' => 'Audi', 'model' => 'A8'];
$engine = ['cylinder' => 6, 'displacement' => '3000cc'];

$merged = [...$car, ...$engine];

var_dump($merged);
```

Will result in:

> [ Error ] Cannot unpack array with string keys

Comment: What's the difference between your example 'item before' and 'item after'

Comment: @crafter your right, I fixed that

Answer (score 14):

Insert an item in the beginning of an **associative array** with **string/custom key**

```
<?php

$array = ['keyOne'=>'valueOne', 'keyTwo'=>'valueTwo'];

$array = array_reverse($array);

$array['newKey'] = 'newValue';

$array = array_reverse($array);
```

**RESULT**

```
[
  'newKey' => 'newValue',
  'keyOne' => 'valueOne',
  'keyTwo' => 'valueTwo'
]
```

Comment: clever, but a bit expensive for large arrays

Answer (score 14):

For an associative array you can just use merge.

```
$arr = array('item2', 'item3', 'item4');
$arr = array_merge(array('item1'), $arr)
```

Comment: array_merge resets array keys. so this is not good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use **array_unshift()** to insert the first element in an array.

Use **array_shift()** to remove the first element of an array.

Comment: Answers are better with examples

Answer (score 7):

There are two solutions:

1. if you have array with keys that matter to you

```php
$new = ['RLG' => array(1,2,3)];
$array = ['s' => array(2,3), 'l' => [], 'o' => [], 'e' => []];

$arrayWithNewAddedItem = array_merge($new, $array);
```

2. if you have an array without any keys.

```php
array_unshift(array, value1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use temporary array and then delete the real one if you want to change it while in cycle:

```
$array = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c');
$temp_array = $array[1];

unset($array[1]);
array_unshift($array , $temp_array);
```

the output will be:

```
array(0 => 'b', 1 => 'a', 2 => 'c')
```

and when are doing it while in cycle, you should clean `$temp_array` after appending item to array.