# Merging two arrays with the "+" (array union operator) How does it work?

Tags: php, arrays, merging-data

I have some code that appears to merge the data from two arrays using `+=`, but it doesn't include all of the elements in the element.  How does it work?

Example:

```
$test = array('hi');
$test += array('test', 'oh');
var_dump($test);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "hi"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "oh"
}
```

What does `+` mean when used on arrays in PHP?

Comment: I notice your question had `+=` and the accepted answer had `+`. From my testing they seem to behave the same.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) sums it up pretty well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @RobbieAverill - this is the question that that Reference question refers to. So if anything that Reference question is the duplicate

Comment: Is anyone else slightly horrified that such a fundamental thing as array concatenation has to be done through `array_merge`? It's as if arrays are by default associative arrays and numeric arrays are second class citizens.

Comment: (First comment of the documentation)[http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php#86379] is as good as any of these answers.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP Manual on Language Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

So if you do

```
$array1 = ['one',   'two',          'foo' => 'bar'];
$array2 = ['three', 'four', 'five', 'foo' => 'baz']; 

print_r($array1 + $array2);
```

You will get

```
Array
(
    [0] => one   // preserved from $array1 (left-hand array)
    [1] => two   // preserved from $array1 (left-hand array)
    [foo] => bar // preserved from $array1 (left-hand array)
    [2] => five  // added from $array2 (right-hand array)
)
```

So the logic of `+` is equivalent to the following snippet:

```
$union = $array1;

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (false === array_key_exists($key, $union)) {
        $union[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

If you are interested in the details of the C-level implementation head to

- php-src/Zend/[zend_operators.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c)

---

Note, that `+` is different from how [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) would combine the arrays:

```
print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

would give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => one   // preserved from $array1
    [1] => two   // preserved from $array1
    [foo] => baz // overwritten from $array2
    [2] => three // appended from $array2
    [3] => four  // appended from $array2
    [4] => five  // appended from $array2
)
```

See linked pages for more examples.

Comment: Is the order of keys after `+` operation guaranteed by the **specs**?

Comment: @Pacerier PHP produced by php.net doesn't have a formal spec, but both the `+` and `array_merge` call `zend_hash_merge` under the hood.  This is also expected, since in PHP arrays are implemented as ordered hash maps.

Comment: @Pacerier The php.net online docs are the closest record to a specification, but IMO those docs fall way short of a true spec: one, they're updated after the code is written; two, they're not written to cover every special usage.

Comment: @bishop, It has been over 20 years, Has no one stepped forward with a proposal of a real specs then?

Comment: @Pacerier To clarify Gordon's link, that specification is for HHVM. While HHVM "deliberately recreates PHP.net bugs and oddities", it should be not be considered a formal specification for PHP as published by PHP.net.

Comment: @Pacerier Stas has completed a working draft spec for [PHP 5.6](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/PHP-5.6/spec/00-specification-for-php.md), however it doesn't appear to address this question.  I'll raise it for clarification.

Comment: @bishop, The question is whether Zend will surrender PHP to Facebook. Facebook could simply purchase `php.net` from Zend. Also, by "Stas" you are talking about "Stas Malyshev"?

Comment: The behaviour of PHP's `+` and `array_merge` is perverse and unintuitive. They're the opposite way round from what a plain-English reading would intuitively tell you 'adding' or 'merging' arrays would do. Other languages/libraries use `+` to concatenate lists (e.g. in Python) and "merge" functions to add the key/value pairs from one object onto another (e.g. in lodash). Yet in PHP it's the other way round; `array_merge` can be used for concatenating list-like arrays but `+` cannot. Unlike `array_merge`,  `+` always performs the operation that would be called a "merge" in any other language.

Comment: @MarkAmery definitely agree, it seems like numeric arrays are second class citizens to associative arrays, or possibly they just are associative arrays with numeric keys under the hood. I think there could just be a `array_concat` method as an alias for `array_merge`. This would be consistent with Python as [dict concatenation is treated the same as merging them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781571/how-to-concatenate-two-dictionaries-to-create-a-new-one-in-python#1784128).

Comment: @icc97 they are indeed only HashMaps. See https://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html

Comment: I've tried [submitting a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73576) to see if an alias `array_concat` could be created for `array_merge`.

Answer (score 24):

The best example I found for using this is in a config array.

```
$user_vars = array("username"=>"John Doe");
$default_vars = array("username"=>"Unknown", "email"=>"no-reply@domain.com");

$config = $user_vars + $default_vars;
```

The `$default_vars`, as it suggests, is the array for default values.
The `$user_vars` array will overwrite the values defined in `$default_vars`.
Any missing values in `$user_vars` are now the defaults vars from `$default_vars`.

This would `print_r` as:

```
Array(2){
    "username" => "John Doe",
    "email" => "no-reply@domain.com"
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

This operator takes the union of two arrays (same as array_merge, except that with array_merge duplicate keys are overwritten).

The documentation for array operators is found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

Comment: A word of caution for beginners here, the result of the operation is **null** if any one of the arrays is **null**. Some might not care about this assuming since it is a union operation, the result will be the proper (not-null) array if one of them is null. But, that holds true if one of the arrays is an **empty** array.

Comment: So, as a good practice, I think, we should initialize the input arrays as empty arrays. What do you guys say?

Answer (score 6):

Carefull with numeric keys, if they should be preserved or if you don't want to loose anything

```
$a = array(2 => "a2", 4 => "a4", 5 => "a5");
$b = array(1 => "b1", 3 => "b3", 4 => "b4");
```

union

```
print_r($a+$b);
Array
(
    [2] => a2
    [4] => a4
    [5] => a5
    [1] => b1
    [3] => b3
)
```

merge

```
print_r(array_merge($a, $b));
Array
(
    [0] => a2
    [1] => a4
    [2] => a5
    [3] => b1
    [4] => b3
    [5] => b4
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator produces the same results as [array_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php). However since the operator arguments are reversed, the ordering of the resulting array may also be different.

Expanding on another example from this page:

```
$array1 = array('one', 'two', 'foo' => 'bar');
$array2 = array('three', 'four', 'five', 'foo' => 'baz'); 

print_r($array1 + $array2);
print_r(array_replace($array2, $array1)); //note reversed argument order
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one   // preserved from $array1
    [1] => two   // preserved from $array1
    [foo] => bar // preserved from $array1
    [2] => five  // added from $array2
)
Array
(
    [0] => one   // preserved from $array1
    [1] => two   // preserved from $array1
    [2] => five  // added from $array2
    [foo] => bar // preserved from $array1
)
```

Comment: Is the order of `+` guaranteed by the specs? What about `array_replace`?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Array plus operation treats all array as assoc array.
> 2. When key conflict during plus, left(previous) value will be kept

I post the code below to make things clear.

`$a + $b = array_plus($a, $b)`

```
function array_plus($a, $b){
    $results = array();
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) if(!isset($results[$k]))$results[$k] = $v;
    foreach($b as $k=>$v) if(!isset($results[$k]))$results[$k] = $v;
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: @Tamlyn's code run seems to prove that your claim *"array plus operation treats all array as assoc array"* is wrong.

Comment: @Pacerier that key could be integer as well.

Answer (score 1):

From https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/
[image]

> That being said, we could think of the + operator as kinda redundant, since the same can be achieved with array_replace function.
>
> However, there are cases, where it comes in handy: say you have an $options array being passed to a function/method, and there are also defaults to be used as fallback:

```php
// we could do it like this
function foo(array $options)
{
   $defaults = ['foo' => 'bar'];
   
   $options = array_replace($defaults, $options);
 
   // ...
}
 
// but + here might be way better:
function foo(array $options)
{
   $options += ['foo' => 'bar'];
 
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It will append the new array to the previous.

Answer (score -6):

```
$var1 = "example";
$var2 = "test";
$output = array_merge((array)$var1,(array)$var2);
print_r($output);
```

Array ( [0] => example [1] => test )

Comment: This thread mentions a few times how array_merge() is NOT congruent.

Comment: @doublejosh, "congruent"? Meaning?

Comment: They are not the same.