# Union of two arrays containing associative arrays while keeping only unique rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, array-merge

I Want to Union 2 array `$A` and `$B` Example:

```
$A = Array(
    0=>array(
            'lable' =>"label0",
            'id_poste'=>1,
            'id_part'=>11
    ),
    1=>array(
            'lable' =>"label1",
            'id_poste'=>2,
            'id_part'=>12
            ),
    2=>array(
            'lable' =>"label2",
            'id_poste'=>3,
            'id_part'=>13
    ),
    3=>array(
            'lable' =>"label3",
            'id_poste'=>4,
            'id_part'=>14
            )
);

$B = Array(
    0=>array(
            'lable' =>"label0",
            'id_poste'=>1,
            'id_part'=>11
    ),
    1=>array(
            'lable' =>"label1_X",
            'id_poste'=>2,
            'id_part'=>12
            ),
    2=>array(
            'lable' =>"label2",
            'id_poste'=>3,
            'id_part'=>13
    ),
    3=>array(
            'lable' =>"label3_X",
            'id_poste'=>4,
            'id_part'=>14
            )
);
```

The result of union between these two array will be

```
/*
$result => Array(
    0=>array(
            'lable' =>"label0",
            'id_poste'=>1,
            'id_part'=>11
    ),
    1=>array(
            'lable' =>"label1",
            'id_poste'=>2,
            'id_part'=>12
            ),
    2=>array(
            'lable' =>"label1_X",
            'id_poste'=>2,
            'id_part'=>12
            )       
    3=>array(
            'lable' =>"label2",
            'id_poste'=>3,
            'id_part'=>13
    ),
    4=>array(
            'lable' =>"label3",
            'id_poste'=>4,
            'id_part'=>14
            ),
    5=>array(
            'lable' =>"label3_X",
            'id_poste'=>4,
            'id_part'=>14
            )
);
*/
```

I have tried with :

```
$C = $A+$B;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($C);
echo '</pre>'
```

But the result is not what I expected ? Anybody could help please?

Thanks

EIDT:

if using `array_merge($A, $B);`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label0
        [id_poste] => 1
        [id_part] => 11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label1
        [id_poste] => 2
        [id_part] => 12
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label2
        [id_poste] => 3
        [id_part] => 13
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label3
        [id_poste] => 4
        [id_part] => 14
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label0
        [id_poste] => 1
        [id_part] => 11
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label1_X
        [id_poste] => 2
        [id_part] => 12
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label2
        [id_poste] => 3
        [id_part] => 13
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [lable] => label3_X
        [id_poste] => 4
        [id_part] => 14
    )
```

)

Like we see here the array is duplicated : So we using `array_unique` But we still got an error or warning .

`Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\PHP\array_union.php on line 86`

Comment: Simply use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Hi find my edited answer... It gives me correct result...and also no error solution.. Added `sort_flags` parameter of array_unique()...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get a solution that is kind a tricky.
I will merge A and its difference with B. To determine this difference, I use array_udiff:
I think it's tricky because it relies on the identification with lable key.

```
$C = array_merge($A, 
            array_udiff($B, $A, 
                        function($a,$b){
                            return strcmp($a['lable'],$b['lable']);
                        }
           )
);
```

Comment: Another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148694/how-to-combine-2-associative-arrays-in-php-such-that-we-do-not-overwrite-any-dup#answer-2152054

Comment: This is not a solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_merge($A, $B);
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

use `array_merge()` for this purpose

```
$C = array_merge($A,$B);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($C);
echo '</pre>'
```

see working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/LrVHn3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge()` for this.. Since you need to remove duplicates, u must also use `array_unique()`....

```
$C = array_unique(array_merge($A,$B), SORT_REGULAR);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($C);
echo '</pre>'
```

See [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

It gives me correct result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label0
            [id_poste] => 1
            [id_part] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label1
            [id_poste] => 2
            [id_part] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label2
            [id_poste] => 3
            [id_part] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label3
            [id_poste] => 4
            [id_part] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label1_X
            [id_poste] => 2
            [id_part] => 12
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [lable] => label3_X
            [id_poste] => 4
            [id_part] => 14
        )

)
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\PHP\array_union.php on line 81

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$input = array_merge( $A, $B );
$input = array_map( "unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)) );

var_dump( $input );
```