# iterate through range of numbers to add as keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have a range of 67 numbers, something like 256 through to 323, which I want to add to an existing array. it doesn't matter what the values are.

looking for code to iterate through those numbers to add them as keys to the array without adding each one at a time

Comment: By *it doesnt matter what the values are* you mean "they do already exist but are not important for the question" or "they do not exist and you dont care what they will be"? In other words, is this about merging a subset of an array into another or is it about padding an array with keys?

Answer (score 3):

Try [array_fill_keys](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) and [range](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
$existingArray =  array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$existingArray += array_fill_keys(range(256,323), null);
```

Use whatever you like instead of `null`. You could also use [array_flip()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) instead of array_fill_keys(). You'd get the index keys as values then, e.g. 256 => 1, 257 => 2, etc.

Alternatively, use [array_merge](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of the `+` operator. [Depends on the outcome you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php/2140094#2140094).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) eg `range(256,323)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) functions.

Something like:

```
<?php

$arr = array(1,2,3); // existing array.
$new_ele = range(256,323); 

// add the new elements to the array.
$arr= array_merge($arr,$new_ele); 

var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Comment: This would not add the values as keys.

Answer (score 0):

push(); could be a look worth, or you can do  it 
like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
$anotherArray[$i] = $array[$i];

}
```