# insert value at the beginning of an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

my array is

`$hello= array( Code => 'TIR', Description => 'Tires', Price => 100 )`

now i want to add a value in array beginning of an array not the end of an array.... and results i want is

`$hello= array( ref=>'World', Code => 'TIR', Description => 'Tires', Price => 100 )`

**UPDATE**

actually i need any value that is coming will be added in the beginning of an array....this is not single value.. ref=world.... this is coming from output...like if i add quantity=50, then it should be added beginning of an array  before 'ref' an array should be

`$hello= array(quantity=>'50', ref=>'World', Code => 'TIR', Description => 'Tires', Price => 100 )`

Comment: Non-numeric array indices are strings, and should thus be quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [**array_merge()**](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

```
$hello = array ("Code" => "Tir" .....); // you should really put quotes 
                                        // around the keys!
$world = array ("ref" => "World");

$merged = array_merge($world, $hello);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `+` operator:

```
$hello = array( 'Code' => 'TIR', 'Description' => 'Tires', 'Price' => 100 );
$hello = array('ref' => 'World') + $hello;
print_r($hello);
```

would give

```
Array
(
    [ref] => World
    [Code] => TIR
    [Description] => Tires
    [Price] => 100
)
```

Like Pekka said, you should put quotes around the keys. The [PHP manual explicitly states omitting quotes is wrong usage](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar). You might also want to check out [my answer about the difference between using the `+` operator vs using `array_merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php/2140094#2140094) to decide which you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a= array( 'a' => 'a' );
$b = array( 'b' => 'b' );

$res = $b + $a;
//result: ( 'b' => 'b', 'a' => 'a' )
```

Answer (score 0):

$hello = array_merge(array('ref'=>'World'), $hello);