# How to 1 output from 2 output

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How to 1 output from 2 output ?

```
<?php

[a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 72.89.122.00:50827
            [1] => 62.173.145.00:17211
        );

[b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 61.10.231.00:52151
            [1] => 66.171.81.00:41787
        );
?>
```

I need output:

```
[total] => Array
        (
            [0] => 72.89.122.00:50827
            [1] => 62.173.145.00:17211
            [2] => 61.10.231.00:52151
            [3] => 66.171.81.00:41787
        );
```

Comment: So you have **array**'s which you want to **merge**, so the logic function name **()** would be: [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: how to use array_merge ()?

Comment: Ask google OR read the manual! We can't learn for you

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the indicated question - that one is about flattening  arrays that contain arrays, where this is about merging distinct arrays.  It's more a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650177/cant-concatenate-2-arrays-in-php

Comment: @stvcisco Since OP doesn't show us the **real** array structure right now this seems like a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array_merge(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$newArray = array_merge($a,$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_merge` function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).