# PHP: Adding arrays together

Tags: php, arrays

Could someone help me explain this? I have two snippets of code, one works as I expect, but the other does not.

**This works**

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
$b = array('c' => 3);
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);

// Output
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```

**This does not**

```
$a = array('a', 'b');
$b = array('c');
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);

// Output
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

What is going on here?? Why doesn't the second version also add the two arrays together? What have I misunderstood? What should I be doing instead? Or is it a bug in PHP?

Comment: **possible duplicate of [+ operator for array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)**

Comment: Your example is wrong. The second output should be `1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'`.

Comment: @Gordon: No, I sort of did know what the + operator meant, just... misunderstood it a bit :p

Comment: @Tgr: It was wrong, but I fixed it now. And that is what I get outputted here now at least...

Comment: that's why I linked the other post. So you understand it better ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is documented and correct: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

> The + operator appends elements of remaining keys from the right handed array to the left handed, whereas duplicated keys are NOT overwritten.

So I guess it's not a bug in php and what is suppose happen. I hadn't noticed this before either.

Comment: You could say it is a design flaw. `array_merge`-ing two associative arrays leads to strange results when some of the keys are numeric (which is pretty common for arrays representing database records).

Comment: Actually, it's by design and really useful if you need to merge two arrays and preserve numerical keys (or rather merge arrays where the numerical keys are significant). As others here have said, you should use array_merge().

Answer (score 28):

to be short, this works because if you print_r both $a and $b you have:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [c] => 3
)
```

as you can see all elements have different keys...

as for the second example arrays, if you print $a and $b you have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
)
```

and that 0 key for both 'a' and 'c' is the issue here, the elements of second array with same keys are discarded... if you do:

```
$c = $b + $a; // instead of $c = $a + $b;
```

the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => b
)
```

Answer (score 21):

To add two non-associative arrays you need to use the [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) function:

> Merges the elements of one or more
>   arrays together so that the values of
>   one are appended to the end of the
>   previous one. It returns the resulting
>   array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same
>   string keys, then the later value for
>   that key will overwrite the previous
>   one. If, however, the arrays contain
>   numeric keys, the later value will not
>   overwrite the original value, but will
>   be appended.
>
> If only one array is given and the
>   array is numerically indexed, the keys
>   get reindexed in a continuous way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just undocumented behaviour, but I'm probably wrong about that. Either way, if you're trying to put arrays together like that, use `array_merge`

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

When working on arrays, the plus operator doesn't overwrite indexes, nor does it reindex the arrays. In your example `c` has index 0 just as `a`, so it's discarded. Use array_merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_splice($a,count($a),0,$b); //array $a becomes a group of $a and $b arrays.
```

P.S. it's for indexed arrays (not associative)