# if $a and $b are bothe arrays the what would be the result of $a+$b?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [+ operator for array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

If `$a` and `$b` are both arrays, what is the result of `$a + $b`?

Comment: Surely you can crrate a test script to find out.. Why the question?

Comment: duplicate of [+ operator for array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-plus-merge-arrays-php/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

```
Union of $a and $b.
```

> The + operator appends elements of
>   remaining keys from the right handed
>   array to the left handed, whereas
>   duplicated keys are NOT overwritten.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(4, 5, 6);
$c = $a + $b;

print_r($c);
```

results in this for me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

**BUT:**

```
<?php

$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$b = array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$c = $a + $b;

print_r($c);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
)
```

So it would appear that the answer here depends on how your arrays are keyed.

Comment: I just did the same with *exactly* the same variable names, values and functions (before it was edited) ;)

Answer (score 1):

My test

```
$ar1 = array('1', '2');
$ar2 = array('3', '4');
$test = $ar1 + $ar2;
print_r($test);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now try this experiment

```
$a = array( 0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            4 => 3
          );
$b = array( 2 => 4,
            4 => 5,
            6 => 6
          );
$c = $a + $b;

var_dump($c);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do something like `$result = $a + $b;` then `$result` will be assigned to the first argument, in this case `$a`.

Comment: Not if $a and $b are keyed arrays.

Comment: Suggest you look a little more deeply into this Evernoob, the behaviour isn't quite as simplistic as you say