# Php concatenation of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I have the next array($columsData):

```
Array
(
    [avatar] => Array
        (
            [title] => Avatar
            [sort] => 
            [no_html_escape] => 1
        )
    [title] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [sort] => 
        )
)
```

And how can i make this array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [title] => Id
            [no_html_escape] => 1
        )
    [avatar] => Array
        (
            [title] => Avatar
            [no_html_escape] => 1
        )
    [title] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [no_html_escape] => 1
        )
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? Where is the `id` array coming from? What does the array represent?

Comment: You can use the `+` operator to concat arrays?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php/2140094#2140094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$columsData['id']['title'] = 'id';
$columsData['id']['no_html_escape'] = 1;
```