# compare two arrays of numbers and remove duplicates in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, array-intersect

OK i have two groups of mobile numbers (from mysql) which i need to process, the problem is i need to remove duplicate numbers from the results.

Someone told me about "array_intersect" but I am not very good at these things and I don't see any good examples on the PHP website.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP combining arrays.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941302/php-combining-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_intersect` isn't quite right — that finds numbers that are in both arrays

```
$uniques = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

This merges the two arrays together and then filters out all the unique results (with `array_unique`)

Answer (score 3):

Use the array_unique function.

```
$myArray = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5);
$myArray2 = array_unique($myArray);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 2):

Put both lists into one array and then run it through [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote about using MySQL, better try using something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone_number FROM table
```

With `DISTINCT` each row in the resultset will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_unique function. Here is an example:

```
$start = array(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5);
$unique_result = array_unique($start);
```