# How to combaine multiple array to one array

Tags: php

I want to need multiple array combaine in one array

I have array

```
array(
  0=> test 1
)
array(
  0=> test 2
)
array(
  0=> test 3
)
```

I need expected output

```
`array(
 0=>Test1
1=>Test2
2=>test3

)`
```

Comment: `cakephp` **and** `laravel`? And `mysql`? Don't spam tags

Comment: What have you got so far? Where did you fail?

Comment: Is there any specification as to why `test1` and `test2` have their first letter uppercased? Why not `test3`?

Comment: Use `array_merge`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP combining arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941302/php-combining-arrays)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't concatenate 2 arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650177/cant-concatenate-2-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array('test_1');
$b = array('test_2');
$c = array('test_3');
print_r(array_merge($a,$b,$c));
```

O/P - `Array ( [0] => test_1 [1] => test_2 [2] => test_3 )`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `array_merge()` for this. The array_merge() function merges one or more arrays into one array.If two or more array elements have the same key, the last one overrides the others.

Syntax:

```
array_merge(array ...$arrays): array
```

Example:

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```

You can check more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing well and good.
So, as per your requirement i found solution to get result.

`$array1 = [0 => "Test 1"]; $array2 = [0 => "Test 2"]; $array3 = [0 => "Test 3"];`

`print_r(array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3));`

In the above example you have to merge the n number of array with single array, so for that you need to use array function which is array_merge(array ...$array).

What is array_merge()?

The array_merge() function merges one or more arrays into one array.

Tip: You can assign one array to the function, or as many as you like.

Note: If two or more array elements have the same key, the last one overrides the others.