# Merge array into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge an associative array into another associative array. I know php's array_merge but it returns a new array. That's not what I want.

Eg

```
$ar1 = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3);
$ar2 = array('four'=>4, 'five'=>5);
```

I want to know that is there a php function which I can use to merge $ar2 into $ar1. The result should be,

```
$ar1 = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3, 'four'=>4, 'five'=>5);
```

Comment: Can't you just use `array_merge` like this then: `$ar1 = array_merge($ar1, $ar2);`

Comment: Without using array_merge you'd have to write a loop that combines them manually. Why can't you have a new array?

Comment: @KristerAndersson Yep :). I feel shame on me. Thanks anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP append one array to another (not array\_push or +)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268871/php-append-one-array-to-another-not-array-push-or)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ar1 = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3);
$ar2 = array('four'=>4, 'five'=>5);
```

use `array_merge`

```
$array3 = array_merge($ar1,$ar2);
```

it will merge the 2 array and store it in `$array3`. You can use `$ar1` also.

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/KzCHIB

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar1 = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3);
$ar2 = array('four'=>4, 'five'=>5);

$ar1 = array_merge($ar1, $ar2);

print_r($ar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way is to assign output of array_merge to your first array. 
**Is this you want**

```
<?php
$ar1 = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3);
$ar2 = array('four'=>4, 'five'=>5);

$ar1 = array_merge($ar1,$ar2);

print_r($ar1);
?>
```