# Add array values at the start of each subArray from other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, `$array1` and `$array2`, now I want to take the values from `$array2` and put each element at the start of each subArray from `$array1`

First array:

```
$array1 = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 15 
            [3] => 6               
    )   
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 12

    )    
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5             
    )    
)
```

Second array:

```
$array2 = Array (
    [0] => Outlook
    [1] => Temp
    [2] => Humidity        
)
```

Expected output (modified/new values bold):

```
$array1 = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => 'Outlook'
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 15 
            [4] => 6        
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 'Temp'
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 12         
    )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 'Humidity'
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 5            
    )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP append one array to another (not array\_push or +)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268871/php-append-one-array-to-another-not-array-push-or)

Comment: Where are you stuck in doing this?

Comment: i cant not understand how i can do this how i merge two array as  i want

Comment: You can do this multiple ways. 1) Take a look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and loop through your second array. Plus look at [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) 2) Or you look at [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and at `array_unshift()`. Read the pages carefully, look at the examples, try to write some code, and if you get stuck post the attempt here. And we will help you to finish it :)

Comment: @baboizk Op wants to merge the array differently than described in the dupe.

Comment: @Rizier123 apologies, you might be right. I did not ask/comment on specific situation like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
array_walk
(
    $array1,
    function( &$row, $key, $kind )
    {
        array_unshift( $row, $kind[$key] );
    },
    $array2 
);
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/542212)**</kbd>

[`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) modify an array using a custom function. The callable function arguments are the array item (note that we have to set it [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) using `&`), the array key (optional) and an optional custom parameter (in our case, `$array2`). Inside the function, with [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)) we can prepend to each item the relative `$array2` item, selecting it by key `$key`.

---

- Read more about [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
- Read more about [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)
- Read more about [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
- Read more about [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: sir its not worked like i mention in question its give offset error

Comment: just sir i have a minor problem actually above i mention $array2 thats start with index zero actually  my $array2 is started index one like bellow   $array2 = Array (
    [1] => Outlook
    [2] => Temp
    [3] => Humidity        
)

Comment: sir my $array2 is start from index 1 not 0 .thats why i face offset error kindly guide me

Comment: You can use `$array2 = array_values( $array2 )` to reset keys.