# problem in including all php files of a directory in php

Tags: php, arrays

I included all php files of a directory , and it worked just fine

```
  foreach (glob("directory/*.php") as $ScanAllFiles)
  {
      include_once($ScanAllFiles); 
  }
```

but problem is that the content of these files are all like this

```
$workers = array(
blah,
blah
);


$employers = array(
blah,
blah
);
```

now when i include all these files , its some how meaningless cause i will have repeated $workers and $employers

and i just want them to be like this

```
$workers = array()
$workers .=array()
```

now is there anyway to fetch $vars without editing all php files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [+ operator for array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Comment: these are two different things , i want to merge all $employers in all php files of a directory ! and the same thing for $workers . cause I'm not allowed to edit php files.

Comment: Also lots of Search Results for [Merge Two Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merge+two+arrays+[php])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to merge your arrays, by yourself, using for instance the [**`array_merge()`**](http://www.php.net/array_merge) function :

```
$all_workers = array();
foreach (glob("directory/*.php") as $ScanAllFiles) {
    $workers = array();     // So if there is no $workers array in the current file,
                            // there will be no risk of merging anything twice
                            // => At worse, you'll merge an empty array (i.e. nothing) into $all_workers
    include $ScanAllFiles;
    $all_workers = array_merge($all_workers, $workers);
}
```

*PHP will not do this automatically : basically, including a file is exactly like copy-pasting its entire content at the line you put your `include` statement.*

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to include those files within a function so that you have scoped variables instead of globals.

```
$employees = array();

foreach (glob("directory/*.php") as $ScanAllFiles)
{
    $employees = array_merge(my_include($ScanAllFiles), $employees);
}

function my_include($file) {

    include_once($file);

    return $employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might be best to rewrite the particular scripts. A not quite readable but functioning approach would be:

```
$workers = (array)$workers + array(
     blah,
     blah,
);
```

Albeit the `+` approach is not always best, use `array_merge` preferrably.