# Slow functions cause by array_merge in loops

Tags: php, filter, array-merge

I have two functions which appear to be slowing down PHP, and I believe its to do with the use of array_merge in the loops, only I am struggling to figure out how I can get around not doing so.

```
function fuseOzone($field) {
    global $ozone;
    if(isset($ozone['all'])) {
        foreach($ozone['all'] as $priority => $functions) {
            if(isset($ozone[$field][$priority])) {
                $ozone[$field][$priority] = array_merge($ozone['all'][$priority], $ozone[$field][$priority]);
            } else {
                $ozone[$field][$priority] = array_merge($ozone['all'][$priority], array());
                $ozone[$field][$priority] = array_unique($ozone[$field][$priority]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($ozone[$field])) {
        ksort($ozone[$field]);
    }
}
```

```
function applyOzone($field, $content) {
    global $ozone;
    fuseOzone($field);
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    if(isset($ozone[$field])) {
        foreach($ozone[$field] as $priority => $functions) {
            if(!is_null($functions)) {
                foreach($functions as $function) {
                    if(!function_exists($function['function'])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $all_args = array_merge(array($content), $args);
                    $function_name = $function['function'];
                    $accepted_args = $function['accepted_args'];
                    if($accepted_args === 1) {
                        $the_args = array($content);
                    } elseif($accepted_args > 1) {
                        $the_args = array_slice($all_args, 0, $accepted_args);
                    } elseif($accepted_args === 0) {
                        $the_args = null;
                    } else {
                        $the_args = $all_args;
                    }
                    $content = call_user_func_array($function_name, $the_args);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

These functions are part of a larger class which essentially operates much like Wordpress actions. I.e. I can hook into a portion of content with filtering or such.

Comment: _appear to be slowing down PHP_ and _I believe its to do with_ don't make it sound like you have truly identified the cause of your problem with certainty. What makes you believe the slowdown is caused by `array_merge()`? Have you run tests?

Comment: `$ozone[$field][$priority] = array_merge($ozone['all'][$priority], array());` why do you even merge with an empty array? And you create the variable $functions but you are not using it. Why? Instead you use the array and keys to point at the same thing.

Comment: @jibsteroos looking at Xdebug those functions are taking the most amount of time, and in looking at possibilities as to why, and reading up on code improvements I found many articles stating that array_merge in a loop is a bad idea due to resource consumption.

Comment: then you've tried to optimize with e.g. [optimizing-array-merge-operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348339/optimizing-array-merge-operation#:~:text=array_merge()%20is%20significantly%20slower,will%20overwrite%20the%20previous%20one.), or other solutions and you've not seen improved perfomance? What have you tried?

Comment: @Andreas this is inherited code, so I didn't write these functions myself, just have the task of figuring out what I can trim/rewrite to improve things. I have already made things 50% faster by swapping out an array_filter with a foreach loop.