# How to speed up a HTTP get request that loads larg data as a response

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, get

I have this code with a while loop to exceed the limit of the API of 1000 records by merging all the arrays in the response together in one array and passing it to the view, but it takes too long waiting time, is there any better way to do it and speed up the process?
this is my code

```
public function guzzleGet()
{
    $aData = [];
    $sCursor = null;

    while($aResponse = $this->guzzleGetData($sCursor))
    {
        if(empty($aResponse['data']))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $aData = array_merge($aData, $aResponse['data']);

            if(empty($aResponse['meta']['next_cursor']))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $sCursor = $aResponse['meta']['next_cursor'];
            }
        }
    }

   
    $user = Auth::user()->name;
    return view("".$user."/home")->with(['data' => json_encode($aData)]);


}

protected function guzzleGetData($sCursor = null)
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $token = 'token';
    
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://data.beneath.dev/v1/user/project/table', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ],
        'query' => [
            'limit' => 1000,
            'cursor' => $sCursor
        ]
    ]);

    if($response->getBody())
    {
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true) ?: [];
    }

    return [];
}
```

Comment: You could install [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see what makes it slow (query time, memory usage, CPU usage etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to debug where is the bottleneck. If the reason its slow is your network/bandwidth,  then that might be the issue. It could also be the API is limiting your download speed.

Another bottleneck could be the download speed of the client. Since you are building up a big array, when the server sends it to the client it needs to download it and can take time.

You could potentially increase speed a little by reusing the same curl handler, or guzzle client. Another are you could improve is the array_merge, you can use your own custom logic explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23348715/8485567.

If you have control of the external API, make sure to use gzip and HTTP/2 or possibly even gRPC instead of http.

However I would recommend you do this on the client side using JS, like that you can avoid the additional bandwidth it takes for the client to download it from the server. You could use the same approach of limit 1000, or could even stream the response as it comes in and render it.