# Unserialize and combine two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays stored serialized in my database, when individually unzerialized they might output:

```
    array(1 => 0, 
    2 => 1, 
    3 => 4, 
    4 => 0, 
    5 => 2);


    array(2 => 3,
    4 => 1);
```

I need to merge them in such a way that the values of the 2nd array override those in the 1st, but also preserve any values in array 1 that are not in array 2 for example the ideal output of the 2 combined would be:

```
    array(1 => 0, 
    2 => 3, 
    3 => 4, 
    4 => 1, 
    5 => 2);
```

When I attempt to combine them I get the error:

```
    Fatal error: Unsupported operand types
```

This is how I have tried (ref: [Combine two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)):

```
        $array1 = unserialize($row['serialized1']);
        $array2 = unserialize($row['serialized2']);
    $_SESSION['combined_array'] = $array1+$array2;
```

Also:

```
    $_SESSION['combined_array'] = unserialize($row['serialized2'])+unserialize($row['serialized1']);
```

Edit:

I have also tried:

```
    $_SESSION['combined_array'] = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

This does not error, but does not result in any combined array.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `array_replace()`.  It's slightly different than `array_merge()` when dealing with numeric keys:

```
$array1 = unserialize($row['serialized1']);
$array2 = unserialize($row['serialized2']);
$combined_array = array_replace($array1, $array2);
```

This works, notice they are reversed from your code:

```
$combined_array = $array2 + $array1;
```

You will get the `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types` if they are not both arrays, empty or otherwise.

Comment: It seems that it was a matter of array2 occassionally being empty - my bad. But this is a neat solution and it does the trick! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, edited.  They can be empty, but they must be arrays.  [See here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f83e6e5f0365dede6d9fb30eb259c3cbfbd47e0)

Comment: array_replace presevrves the order - but yes + operator does work. Thanks again!