# Merge two associative arrays and group by first level key

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, merge

**$array 1:-**

```
Array
(
    [Test Stock] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
        )

    [CARTON 50 X 50 X 50] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
        )
)
```

**$array2:-**

```
Array
(
    [Test Stock] => Array
        (
            [intInvoiceCount] => 20
        )

    [CARTON 50 X 50 X 50] => Array
        (
            [intInvoiceCount] => 30
        )
)
```

I need a new array combining all together without using loop

```
Array
(
    [Test Stock] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
            [intInvoiceCount] => 20
        )

    [CARTON 50 X 50 X 50] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
            [intInvoiceCount] => 30
        )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_merge_recursive` to do the job.

[**array_merge_recursive**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

> array_merge_recursive() merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Just do:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "Test Stock" => array(
        "intStockCount" => 10
    ),
    "CARTON 50 X 50 X 50" =>  array(
        "intStockCount" => 10
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    "Test Stock" => array(
        "intInvoiceCount" => 20
    ),
    "CARTON 50 X 50 X 50" =>  array(
        "intInvoiceCount" => 30
    )
);

$final = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';

/* OUTPUT
Array
(
    [Test Stock] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
            [intInvoiceCount] => 20
        )

    [CARTON 50 X 50 X 50] => Array
        (
            [intStockCount] => 10
            [intInvoiceCount] => 30
        )

)
*/
```

The important thing to notice here is that you are using the same string `key` in both of your `arrays`. As the PHP docs state

> **...the values for these keys are merged together into an array**

Answer (score 2):

```
  $array1 = array(
    'Test Stock' => array(
        'intStockCount' => 10,
    ),
    'CARTON 50 X 50 X 50' => array(
        'intStockCount' => 10
    )
    );
    $array2 = array(
    'Test Stock' => array(
        'intStockCount' => 10,
    ),
    'CARTON 50 X 50 X 50' => array(
        'intStockCount' => 10
    )
    );
    $result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array1);

    var_dump($result);
```

You have to change your array structure.

For normal array merge :

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: This will not work in this case because the same string keys. The later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @DavidDomain you are right, for this reason you need array_merge_recursive function. I edited my answer. And also need to chage his array structure properly.

Comment: That would be an option. I deleted the down vote, but i would still prefer `array_merge_recursive`. We have to consider that the OP does not want to change the array structure.