# Printing multiple table queries using json_encode in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to print multiple database queries using `json_encode()`. I have this code below that outputs database records using json_encode. This works fine.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include('db.php');

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT username,firstname,lastname FROM user');
$result->execute(array());

$data = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

I need to add another database query so that I can print them together using the same json_encode. Here is the database query that I want to add so that I can print them together using json_encode:

```
<?php

include('db.php');

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT price AS price1,goods AS product FROM provision_table');
$result->execute(array());

$data_pro = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $data_pro[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data_pro);
?>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might hit what you're looking for.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include('db.php');

$result = $db->prepare('select username,firstname,lastname from user');
$result->execute(array());

$data = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$result = $db->prepare('select price as price1,goods as product from provision_table');
$result->execute(array());

$data_pro = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $data_pro[] = $row;
}

// Combine both arrays in a new variable
$all_data['user'] = $data;
$all_data['pro'] = $data_pro;

echo json_encode($all_data);
```

Comment: Hello dear, its not printing or outputting any value. everything value was just empty. I cannot figure out where you initialized $all_data variables.