# how to merge arrays into single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

There are two arrays:

**First Array:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => EXTRA
  [1] => CURRICULAR
)
```

**Second Array:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => ACTIVITIES
  [1] => 50
  [2] => 35
  [3] => THIRTY
  [4] => FIVE
  [5] => PASS
)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array 
(
  [0] => EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES
  [1] => 50
  [2] => 35
  [3] => THIRTY
  [4] => FIVE
  [5] => PASS
)
```

that two arrays should be dynamic,i need to append to first into second ,please help me

Comment: Did you try `array_merge`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You need to [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your first array, and prepend the result to the first value of your second array :

```
$array1 = array('EXTRA', 'CURRICULAR');
$array2 = array('ACTIVITIES', 50, 35, 'THIRTY', 'FIVE', 'PASS');

$string = implode(' ', $array1);
$array2[0] = $string . ' ' . $array2[0];

var_dump($array2);
```

Result :

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES' (length=27)
  1 => int 50
  2 => int 35
  3 => string 'THIRTY' (length=6)
  4 => string 'FIVE' (length=4)
  5 => string 'PASS' (length=4)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,how to get values without using var_dump.

Comment: Use `$array2[0]` to get the first value, `$array2[1]` for the second, etc.

Comment: that should be dynamically working ,we need to take accordingly?

Comment: This will **always** return the second array, with every element of the first array, separated by a space, prepended to its first value.