# PHP array merging

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

I have two array like this:

```
Array(
     [0] => (
         [id] => 1,
         [order_id] => 1,
         [image_url] => /resources/filename1
         ),
     [1] => (
         [id] => 2,
         [order_id] => 1,
         [image_url] => /resources/filename2
         )
)
```

I want to merge `imge_url` in single array because of `order_id`, one order_id have multiple images.

I am expecting array like this:

```
Array(
    [id] => 1,
    [order_id] => 1,
    [image_url] => (
        [0] => "/resources/filename1",
        [1] => "/resources/filename2"
    )
)
```

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the content of your array and not combine two arrays?

Comment: yes @TamasSzoke i want to modify arrray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am sorry my previous answer was not right, this one does, I assume a couple of things:

- Your input can be more than two rows and can have more than one order ID
- I am assigning to ID the first ID with that order ID (if not you can just only assign the ID key.

Here is the code:

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "order_id" => 1,
        "image_url" => "/resources/filename1"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "order_id" => 1,
        "image_url" => "/resources/filename2"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "order_id" => 1,
        "image_url" => "/resources/filename3"
    ],
        [
        "id" => 4,
        "order_id" => 2,
        "image_url" => "/resources/filename4"
    ],
];

foreach($arrays as $array) {
    if(!isset($result[$array['order_id']]['id'])) {
        $result[$array['order_id']]['id']=$array['id'];
    }
    $result[$array['order_id']]['order_id']=$array['order_id'];
    $result[$array['order_id']]['image_url'][]=$array['image_url'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Tested [here](https://3v4l.org/Y25C2).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer (an answer includes some code that shows how it would work).

Comment: This won't produce the correct result: https://3v4l.org/su0XP. _Suggestion:_ Test the code before posting.

Comment: Fixed answer, this one is correct

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Working demo : https://eval.in/1014350

```
$array = array(array(
     'id' => 1,
     'order_id' => 1,
     'image_url' => '/resources/filename1'
     ),array(
     'id' => 2,
     'order_id' => 1,
     'image_url' => '/resources/filename2'
     )
);

foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  if ($item['id'] == 1)
  {
    $data['id'] = $item['id'];
  }
  $data['order_id'] = $item['order_id'];
  $data['image_url'][$key] = $item['image_url'];
}

print_r($data);
```

Program Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [order_id] => 1
    [image_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => /resources/filename1
            [1] => /resources/filename2
        )

)
```

Comment: In my opinion, if the OP shows no attempt of trying to solve the issue themselves, the question is off-topic and should therefor not be answered. Doing that will make the OP and future visitors just keep asking and SO will become a free coding service (which it isn't).

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson because i gave an answer that is why you downvote me, i think its a question and answer site, next time i will not answer such question

Comment: Actually, I haven't down voted this answer since it _does_ answer the question. My comment was just to point out the risk of answering off-topic questions. Yes, it's a Q&A site, but it does have have guidelines that states that you should include your attempts when asking a question. The site is about helping people with issues with their (existing) code. It's not a site for "I want this" and we just give them code.

Comment: for downvoter  its fault from askers who ask such questions so downvote them , pls don't downvote well given answers