# Merge 2 separate arrays into a single array

Tags: php, arrays, statamic

I have getting array like:

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-11-21 [1] => 2020-11-22 [2] => 2020-11-23 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2020-10-11 [1] => 2020-10-12 [2] => 2020-10-13 [3] => 2020-10-14 [4] => 2020-10-15 )
```

Want to combine both arrays in a single array

**expected result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-11-21 [1] => 2020-11-22 [2] => 2020-11-23 [3] => 2020-10-11 [4] => 2020-10-12 [5] => 2020-10-13 [6] => 2020-10-14 [7] => 2020-10-15 )
```

**I have tried array_merge  like:**

```
public function method($format = 'Y-m-d') {
        $arrayObject = $this->context->value('event_date');
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $realEnd = new DateTime($arrayObject['end']); 
        $realEnd->add($interval); 
        $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($arrayObject['start']), $interval, $realEnd); 
       foreach($period as $date) {                  
                $array[] = $date->format($format);  
                
            }

        if (!is_array($array)) { 
                return FALSE; 
        } 

            $result = array(); 
            $a = [];
            array_push($a, $array);
            foreach ($a as $key => $value) { 
              
               // print_r($value);
                if (is_array($value)) { 
                  $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
                } 
                
              } 
              //return ;     
        print_r($result);

    }
```

**getting output is:**

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-11-21 [1] => 2020-11-22 [2] => 2020-11-23 ) Array ( [0] => 2020-10-11 [1] => 2020-10-12 [2] => 2020-10-13 [3] => 2020-10-14 [4] => 2020-10-15 )
```

Please help me to get the result in  single array.

Comment: Array_merge works perfect. See: https://phpize.online/?phpses=60480df91d670271820d755540a0c4d7&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I used `array_merge` it works fine for me , whatever it is ,it's from `array_flatten`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
array_merge ([ array $... ] ) : array
```

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

> Values in the input arrays with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.