# How can I combine 2 array in php or laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I would like to combine 2 arrays into 1 in PHP or laravel. I've searched this site for similar questions but can't seem to find an answer.
Can someone help me with this?

**array 1  -- $insertData  **

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [prid] => 4
        [vendor_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [prid] => 5
        [vendor_id] => 2
    )

)
```

**Array - 2   $requestData **

```
Array
(
[vendor_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2
    )

[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 5
    )

[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 13
        [2] => 14
        [3] => 15
    )
)
```

**Required Output ---- how can I do this array1 and array2 combine into a single array  **

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 4
            [vendor_id] => 1
            [item] => 2
            [qty] => 12
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 4
            [vendor_id] => 1
            [item] => 3
            [qty] => 13
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 5
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [item] => 4
            [qty] => 14
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 5
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [item] => 5
            [qty] => 15
        )
)
```

**My controller**

```
    public function prtmulti(Request $req)
{

    $maxPrId = newpr::max('prid');
    // print_r($maxPrId);
    echo "<pre>";
    $requestData = $req->all();

    if (array_key_exists("vendor_name", $requestData)) {
        $insertData = [];
        $uniqueData = array_unique($requestData["vendor_name"]);
        foreach ($uniqueData as $key => $value) {
                $maxId = $maxPrId+1;
                $insertData[] =  ['prid' => $maxId, 'vendor_id' => $value];
        
                $maxPrId = $maxPrId+1;
        }
    }
    print_r($insertData);
    print_r($requestData);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays)

Comment: your output example show a mixed build aaray, you need a merge or rebuild and add in all data array???

Comment: Please elaborate your arrays a little bit more.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that is an ill-suited duplicate, please retract your vote to close -- it will only call for volunteers to undo from the reopen queue.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using the `array_combine` function in php, for example:

```
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");

$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
print_r($c);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Laravel doesn't offer anything out of the box to execute your desired merging technique (and I don't see why it would bother).

Assuming that the `vendor_id` values in the first array are unique, you will get best performance by creating a lookup array.  `array_column()` can be used to declare an array with `vendor_id` values as keys and `prid` values as values.

Because your `$requestData` has rows with the number of columns desired in the output, loop over the `$requestData['vendor_id']` data and manually generate the desired rows of data in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0GorL))

```
$insertData = [
    ['prid' => 4, 'vendor_id' => 1],
    ['prid' => 5, 'vendor_id' => 2],
];

$requestData = [
    'vendor_id' => [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'item' => [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'qty' => [12, 13, 14, 15]
];

$insertLookup = array_column($insertData, 'prid', 'vendor_id');
$result = [];
foreach ($requestData['vendor_id'] as $index => $vendorId) {
    $result[] = [
        'prid' => $insertLookup[$vendorId],
        'vendor_id' => $vendorId,
        'item' => $requestData['item'][$index],
        'qty' => $requestData['qty'][$index],
    ];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'prid' => 4,
    'vendor_id' => 1,
    'item' => 2,
    'qty' => 12,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'prid' => 4,
    'vendor_id' => 1,
    'item' => 3,
    'qty' => 13,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'prid' => 5,
    'vendor_id' => 2,
    'item' => 4,
    'qty' => 14,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'prid' => 5,
    'vendor_id' => 2,
    'item' => 5,
    'qty' => 15,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `array_merge()` function to merge arrays.
[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$merged_array = array_merge($insertData, $requestData);
```

Comment: im using this **array_merge()** function  but Required Output  not show

Comment: Is your second array an Associative array?