# How to merge these two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge those two arrays and get only the unique key values. Is there a php function for this? array_merge() doesn't work.

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1


)

Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2

)
```

**RESULT ARRAY THAT I WANT**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4

)
```

Comment: what u expect to get in result

Comment: Do you want the *keys only* or the *values* for the keys (in which case I assume the value for a given key is going to be the same in both arrays)?

Comment: the arrays merged with unique keys values. For example I don't want the [16] => 16 to appear two times

Comment: This doesnt clarify it for me. Please give a full example output. Also see [+ operator for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Comment: Also: give the *smallest* example that explains what you need. There's no need to put 15 elements in each array to illustrate.

Comment: please use var_export, not print_r, when dumping arrays :)

Comment: eh, wait. now you also want it sorted and reindexed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$values = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
sort($values);
```

This returns the unique values from array1 and array2 (as per your example).

Try it here: http://codepad.org/CeZewRNT

See [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unqiue).

Answer (score 3):

```
$merged = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following peice of code gives exact what you wants but the question is do you really want the keys in the result are starting from 1 instead of 0? If you don't Arnaud his option is the best solution.

```
$array1 = array(
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 1
);

$array2 =  array(
    1 => 3,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 2
);

$values = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
$keys = array_keys(array_fill_keys($values, ''));
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
asort($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$merged = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```