# Array push error

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble with array_push. It is displaying `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW"` The variable $vars is an associative array for paypal.

```
array_push($vars,
'item_number'.$num => $id,
'item_name'.$num => $cart_item->name,
'amount_'.$num => $cart_item->discount_price,
'quantity_'.$num => $value);



$vars = array (
'cmd' => '_cart',
'charset' => 'utf-8',
'upload' => '1',
'currency_code' => 'HKD',
'amount' => $_SESSION['total'],
'custom' => $user_data->id)
```

Comment: I really don't know what you're doing! Are you pushing an array onto `$vars`? or are you adding the items of the new array to `$vars` one by one?

Comment: BTW, why are you overwriting `$vars` in your second statement? What should be the sctructure of `$vars`? Maybe you could give a link to some documentation of the expected format.

Comment: @AdnanShammout I am adding items one by one. i figured out the answer below by using array_merge instead..

Comment: @LapMingLee, well now you know what to do in your next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=>` syntax is only valid when you define an array. `array_push` can only be used to push elements with auto-incrementing numeric keys.

Maybe you could use `array_merge`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
    'item_number'.$num => $id,
    'item_name'.$num => $cart_item->name,
    'amount_'.$num => $cart_item->discount_price,
    'quantity_'.$num => $value
));
```

Or you could use the `+` operator, thought it behaves quite differently from `array_merge`: [+ operator for array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

```
$vars =  $vars + array(
    'item_number'.$num => $id,
    'item_name'.$num => $cart_item->name,
    'amount_'.$num => $cart_item->discount_price,
    'quantity_'.$num => $value
);
```

Answer (score 1):

from php manual:

If you're going to use `array_push()` to insert a `"key" => "value"`
pair into an array, it can be done using the following:

```
$data[$key] => $value;
```

It is not necessary to use array_push

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array to the stack so your code should reflect that

```
array_push($vars, array(
                     'item_number'.$num => $id,
                     'item_name'.$num => $cart_item->name,
                     'amount_'.$num => $cart_item->discount_price,
                     'quantity_'.$num => $value
                  )
);
```