# add the array returned by the function for each link into one array

Tags: php

hey guys i have the following code

```
$link_repository=array();

foreach ($links as $value) {
   $link_repository=$crawler->fetchLinks($value);
   print_r($link_repository);
   echo 'Count:'.count($link_repository);
   echo '<br><br>';
  }
```

for each link, **fetchLinks** function returns an array of elements. I want to add the array returned by the function for each link into one array. how can i go about it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the other answers here are misunderstanding your question.

`fetchLinks()` returns an array as its result. If you were to simply add this result to the existing `$link_repository` variable, that variable would end up as a multidimensional array - i.e. an array of arrays. For example, if the first call to `fetchLinks()` returned `array(1,2)` and the second call returned `array(3,4)`, this would give you a `$link_repository` variable that looks like `array(array(1,2), array(3,4)`.

What I think you're actually asking for is a way to make it so that the results of all calls to `fetchLinks()` combine to form a one-dimensional array. In the above example, you would want the final result of `$link_repository` to be `array(1,2,3,4)`.

If this is correct, then what you want to do is merge the arrays together with [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$link_repository=array();
foreach ($links as $value) {
   $link_repository= array_merge($link_repository, $crawler->fetchLinks($value));
}
```

I'm not sure about the performance tradeoffs, but you may want to defer the `array_merge` until the end. If you add each `fetchLinks` array as its own element in `$link_repository`, then you can merge them all at once by passing every element in the array to `array_merge` at once by using [`user_call_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

It's worth noting that you may want to use the array union operator, `+`, to merge the arrays, depending on what sort of data `fetchLinks` returns. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) for discussion on how that operator works, and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php) for a discussion on how it differs from `array_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to guess:

```
$link_repository = array();

foreach ($links as $value) {
   $temp = $crawler->fetchLinks($value); //Add to array
   $link_repository = array_merge((array)$link_repository, (array)$temp);
   print_r($link_repository);
   echo 'Count:'.count($link_repository);
   echo '<br><br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: the fetchLinks function returns me an array of elements

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$link_repository[] = $crawler->fetchLinks($value);
```

Comment: this gives me an array in array

suppose i have $link1={1,2,3} and $link2={5,6,7} i want the final array to be $linkrepo={1,2,3,5,6,7}

Answer (score 0):

```
$link_repository=array();

foreach ($links as $value) {
    array_push($link_repository,$crawler->fetchLinks($value));
    //$link_repository[]=$crawler->fetchLinks($value);
    //$link_repository=$crawler->fetchLinks($value); I wouldn't use this
    print_r($link_repository);
    echo 'Count:'.count($link_repository).'<br><br>';
}
return $link_repository;
```

I've supplied two methods of entering data into your array. I wasn't sure which would be best.

Comment: $crawler->fetchLinks($value)   this function returns an array