# Swap my element's order to be the first in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
array(
  [0]=>1
  [1]=>3
  [3]=>5
  [15]=>6
);
```

Arbitrarily I want array[15] to be the first:

```
array(
  [15]=>6
  [0]=>1
  [1]=>3
  [3]=>5
);
```

What is the fastest and most painless way to do this?

Here are the things I've tried:

`array_unshift` - Unfortunately, my keys are numeric and I need to keep the order (sort of like `uasort`) this messes up the keys.

`uasort` - seems too much overhead - the reason I want to make my element the first in my array is to specifically avoid `uasort`! (Swapping elements on the fly instead of sorting when I need them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](https://eval.in/166961) using a [slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and a [union](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php):

```
// get last element (preserving keys)
$last = array_slice($array, -1, 1, true);

// put it back with union operator
$array = $last + $array;
```

*Update:* [as mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421962/2812842), this answer takes the last key and puts it at the front. If you want to arbitrarily move any element to the front:

```
$array = array($your_desired_key => $array[$your_desired_key]) + $array;
```

Union operators take from the right and add to the left (so the original value gets overwritten).

Comment: This assumes the element to swap is always the last element in the array.

Comment: @MarkM I hadn't realised that it needed to be arbitrary. Community wiki this?

Comment: Arbitrary is what's is throwing everything off, OP should be more specific, is he looking for element with key having largest value?

Comment: It might not need to be arbitrary - I interpreted the question that way, but if not, and OP wants the last element, then this is a fine answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the key of the element you want to shift, and that element could be in any position in the array (not necessarily the last element):

```
$shift_key = 15;

$shift = array($shift_key => $arr[$shift_key]);

$arr = $shift + $arr;
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/D37eXMcv)

*Updated - `unset()` not necessary. Pointed out by @FuzzyTree*

Comment: `unset` isn't necessary because the union operator will use the value from the left array when keys exist in both arrays

Answer (score -2):

If #15 is always last you can do

```
$last = array_pop($array); //remove from end
array_unshift($last); //push on front
```

To reorder the keys for sorting simply add

```
$array = array_values($array); //reindex array
```

@Edit - if we don't assume its always last then I would go with ( if we always know wwhat the key is, then most likely we will know its position or it's not a numerically indexed array but an associative one with numeric keys, as op did state "arbitrarily" so one has to assume the structure of the array is known before hand. )

I also dont see the need to reindex them as the op stated that it was to avoid sorting.  So why would you then sort?

```
$item = $array[15];
unset($array[15]); //....etc.
```

Comment: Bad assumption to make.

Comment: [Doesn't run](https://eval.in/166954), and when it does [you lose the keys](https://eval.in/166956).