# PHP $var += array('x','y')

Tags: php, arrays

**Sorry to ask, it's only for my understanding !**
I just start learning php.
I added some values from different method to an array and
 it come to a strange problem that i can't find an answer on the web.
(sorry if it's stupid, i just want to know why it do that.)

My PHP/HTML code:

```
<?php 
$test[] = 1;
$test += array('2','3','4');
$test += array('4in4',5 => '5');
$test[] = 6;
$test[] += 7;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-CA" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<?php echo '<h1>Test de Tableau</h1>','<br>',
    '$test[0] = ',$test[0],'<br>',
    '$test[1] = ',$test[1],'<br>',
    '$test[2] = ',$test[2],'<br>',
    '$test[3] = ',$test[3],'<br>',
    '$test[4] = ',$test[4],'<br>',
    '$test[5] = ',$test[5],'<br>',
    '$test[6] = ',$test[6],'<br>',
    '$test[7] = ',$test[7],'<br>',
    '<h4>count = ',count($test),'/8</h4>'; ?>
</body>
```

And here is the result :
**Test de Tableau**

$test[0] = 1
$test[1] = 3
$test[2] = 4
$test[3] = 
**Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mhx/test/index.php on line 26**

$test[4] = 
**Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mhx/test/index.php on line 27**

$test[5] = 5
$test[6] = 6
$test[7] = 7
**count = 6/8**

Thanks to answer !
MHX

Comment: What problem is there that you want to know?

Comment: ..Sorry again..
I want to know why is there an offset problem on the first parameter of an array(first, second) when i use the "+=" .

Comment: You do realize that the `+=` is addition operator and not the array union operator right?

Comment: Didn't realize the difference. :-(  ..but it still work with the second param !

Comment: possible duplicate of [+ operator for array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Comment: so if i want to add more values, do i need to merge them throught an other array ? as the only good way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have already been answered by this post: [+ operator for array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Essentially, here's what's happening. You initialized your array:

```
$test = [0 => 1];
```

Next, you're adding a new array to it:

```
[0 => '2', 1 => '3', 2 => '4'];
```

The first index already exists, so it's skipped giving us:

```
$test = [0 => 1, 1 => '3', 2 => '4'];
```

Now, you're adding another array:

```
[0 => '4in4', 5 => '5'];
```

Again, the first index exists, so we get:

```
$test = [0 => 1, 1 => '3', 2 => '4', 5 => '5'];
```

By now, you can see that offsets 3 and 4 are missing, hence your notices above. Also, the internal pointer is now at 6 since the last element added was at 5.

You then add 6, followed by 7, giving us the final array:

```
$test = [0 => 1, 1 => '3', 2 => '4', 5 => '5', 6 => 6, 7 => 7];
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** When adding another element to an array, you can just write it like this:

```
$test[] = 1;
```

If you need to merge two arrays, look at [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$test = array_merge($test, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Cheers!

Comment: ok , so if the index already exist, it doesn't goto next, it skip it ! That made it clear.  Thx alot !

Comment: @MHX No problem.  Just be be clear, if you're merging two arrays using the plus sign (+), any indexes from the right array that already exist in the left will be skipped.  If you add to an array (i.e., $test[] = 1) it will be added as the next index, and the internal pointer will be incremented.