# Sums data from an array that has the same id

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query about this project that I am doing, I make a query to my two tables and the data that I call in this case is a quantity number for both, the data displayed is the one that has the same id for both tables.
[image]

The problem occurs when I pass two identifiers and to those two identifiers I want to add their current amount with the amount obtained from the other table

In general, what I want to do is add the amounts obtained, this is my code that I am working with, I would really appreciate if you can help me solve it or guide me.

```
  $id_servis = [1077,1078];
    $sum_quantity_add = Servis_tareas::where('servis_id',$id_servis)->get();
    foreach($sum_quantity_add as $sum_add){
        $quantity_two[] = $sum_add->quantity;
    }
    $quantity_actual = Servis::wherein('id',$id_servis)->get();
    foreach($quantity_actual as $quantity_act){
       $quantity_one[] = $quantity_act->quantity_final;
    }
    dd($id_servicios,$quantity_one, $quantity_two);
     //ERROR 
      $total[] = $quantity_one + $quantity_two;
     //ERROR 
     if(is_numeric($total) < 0 ){
        Servis::wherein('id',$id_servis)->update(['quantity_final' => 0]);
     }else{
        Servis::wherein('id',$id_servis)->update(['quantity_final' => $total]);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql/SQL there is SUM query which handles the addition and they are called Aggregation Functions, and in Laravel there is a Eloquent equivalent of these [Laravel Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#aggregates), using these methods you will be able to count, max, min, avg on the query end rather than in the PHP end.

So, your code will look like

```
        $id_servis        = [1077, 1078];
        $sum_quantity_add = Servis_tareas::where('servis_id', $id_servis)->SUM('quantity');
        $quantity_actual  = Servis::wherein('id', $id_servis)->SUM('quantity_final');
        $total            = $sum_quantity_add + $quantity_actual;
```

What you are trying is treating array as numeric value and adding it, which is wrong, `+` operator behaves totally different while you are using with array, it merges the two array, it is different than array_merge too, so i recommend giving this answer a read [+ operator for array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140094/8630903)

**UPDATED:**

I still don't understand if you want to replace with the SUM from Servis_tareas in the Servis Table or sum the each others quantity and save it, Code below sum the data from both table and save it.

```
$id_servis    = [1077, 1078];
$servisTareas = Servis_tareas::selectRaw("SUM(`quantity`) as total, `servis_id` ")
    ->where('servis_id', $id_servis)
    ->groupBy('servis_id')
    ->having('total', '>', 0)
    ->get();

$foundId     = [];
$servisTotal = Servis::query()->whereIn('id', $id_servis)->pluck('quantity_final', 'id')->toArray();
foreach ($servisTareas as $servisTarea) {
    $foundId[] = $servisTarea->servis_id;
    $total     = $servisTarea->total + ($servisTotal[$servisTarea->servis_id] ?? 0)
    Servis::where('id', $servisTarea->servis_id)->update(['quantity' => $total]);
}
if (!empty($foundId)) {
    Servis::whereNotIn('id', $foundId)->update(['quantity' => 0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but what the code does is add the total and what I want to do is add the new quantity of my "Servis_tareas" model to that of "Servis", when I pass only one ID if it works for me it adds the quantity current plus the new one, but the problem starts when I give it two identifiers, what I want to do is All the Servis that have the same ID of Servis_Tareas add their respective quantity as I show in the image, I want the quantity of the third array go to those of the second array that is to say that the 0 becomes 4 and also the other 0 becomes 2

Comment: @JLDIAZ, updated, check it out

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I can do what I needed, just modify when doing the update, add the square brackets to make it work for me like this
Servis::where('id', [$servisTarea->servis_id])->update(['quantity' => $total]);

Comment: @JLDIAZ Just saw that my last query was mistake it should have been `whereNotIn`