# Adding new values to start of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, push

I tried with array_push(), but I get fatal error.

```
function get_data($table, $id = '', $condition){

   if($id != '')
     array_push( " WHERE `id` = '".$id."' ", $condition );

   ...
}
```

The question is, how to add a value (in my case a string) to the start of an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) is the function you are looking for!

> **array_unshift** — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
print_r($arr);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)   
*/
array_unshift($arr,0);
print_r($arr);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)   
*/
```

Comment: Note that with array_unshift, the arguments will need reversed from what you have (just as for array_push)

Comment: it is in regard to the fact that the OP has the arguments in reverse order (which is the reason for the Fatal error); just want OP to notice that argument order matters :-)

Answer (score 4):

The fatal error is because you have the arguments in reverse order:

```
function get_data($table, $id = '', $condition){

   if($id != '')
     array_push($condition, " WHERE `id` = '".$id."' " );

   ...
}
```

*if* $condition is an array, this will not give a fatal error, but it will place the item at the *end* of the array. As mentioned in other answers, array_unshift is the function to prepend an item.

Answer (score 0):

[array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) should do the trick

Comment: I kind of expected a higher quality in 2012.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739706/how-to-insert-an-item-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-php/1739716#comment120862746_1739716