# How to insert new array to a specific position in multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to insert new array to a specific position in multi dimensional array  below is the code, how it will be done using php

```
$aExistingArray = Array
    (
[pages] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => page1
                [elements] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => text
                                [name] => question2
                                [title] => PSTN
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => radiogroup
                                [name] => question3
                                [title] => Are you satisfied to our services
                                [choices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [value] => item1
                                                [text] => yes
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [value] => item2
                                                [text] => no
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    ))
```

Below is the new array which I want to insert to **elements** position at 0 position, how it will be done using array technique

```
$aToBeInserted = Array
    (
[0] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [name] => name
        [title] => name
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => text
        [name] => question1
        [title] => Test
    )
```

)

Comment: What array are you trying to insert? You've only provided the original array in your post above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an item at the beginning of an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739706/how-to-insert-an-item-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-php)

Comment: The linked duplicate gives you the mechanism. All you really need to provide are the new element and the exact subarray where you wish to insert.

Comment: @ El_Vanja new element have been posted please check

Comment: @BlakeOttinger Question have been edited, kindly check

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution, first find the specific index of array, merge the both arrays and then override with original array.

```
$elementPostition = $arr['pages'][0]['elements'];
$aMergeArray = array_merge($sTobeInsert,$elementPostition );
$arr['pages'][0]['elements'] = $aMergeArray;
```