# Add an key and value as the first element in array

Tags: php

I want to add a key and value in the array as first element without impacting other elements

```
Array
(
[8] => ab
[10] => cd
[11] => ef
[9] => gh
[7] => ik
)
```

Resultant array should be

```
Array
(
[0] => All
[8] => ab
[10] => cd
[11] => ef
[9] => gh
[7] => ik
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an item at the beginning of an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739706/how-to-insert-an-item-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Little Google search can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a dupe

Comment: `$new_array = ['ALL']+$your_array);`

Comment: @nice_dev i don't want to rearrange the key value of array by using array_unshft it re-arrange the key of existing array

Comment: @splash58 your trick work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

```
array_unshift(‘All’);
```

Comment: Hi Joel, your link is in french. Please consider changing it to english (due to this being the english SO site)

Comment: array_unshift break the array keys

Comment: Array
(
[0] => All
[1] => ab
[2] => cd
[3] => ef
[4] => gh
[5] => ik
)
)

Comment: You can only have unique key so yes that is the point.

Comment: @S.Dre Done sorry.

Comment: Don't worry Joel, thanks! @JoelCrypto